# Using my flex application on HTMl5

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, integration

I have flex applications(.swf) that  connect with Visual Studio. i wish HTML5 open my flex application. I try to open with embeeded, but only open .swf, don't have connective with Visual Studio. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, I am a bit confused what you are trying to ask. How does your Flex application connect to Visual Studio?  How do you wish your HTML5 application to open your Flex application?

Comment: My flex application use remote objects to take information from visual studio.
I need to open the generated files from flex (.swf) on html5. i use the tag embeed but only open the visual, like doesnt connect with VS

Comment: I suspect you're confused.  RemoteObject is used to communicate with an application server; not an IDE.  Since you mention Visual Studio, you are probably trying to connect to a .NET Application Server.  That said; I'm still unclear what you wish to do.

Comment: I just need use the .swf generated from flex application in html. using <embeed> or <object> in html, the visual of .swf open, but the connection with server dont work. Sometimes my .swf is black too. better?

Comment: What is the error?  Do you have the debug version of the Flash Player installed?  Have you stepped through your Flex code to make sure it works?

Comment: the code works perfectly, i generated the .swf and try to open in html, but the .swf is black or doesnt connect with the server. And dont have a way to debug why .swf dont connect

Comment: i istal the debug and appear : only file loca-with-system and trustuful SWF local can access the the local resource ( I translated the error)

Comment: It sounds to me like your SWF is trying to access resources it doesn't have access to.  But, without seeing any code it is hard to guess what that may be.

Comment: suddly i found a way, there was missing files. Thank you for helping